# JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, db2, websphere

While connecting Db2 database from my application in WAS 8.5.5.10 I'm facing below exception. My application is built in 1.8 and I mentioned  the db2 configuration details in web.xml. Guide me to resolve this.

```
org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype]
        at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource.getTarget(JndiObjectTargetSource.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:875)
```

**Web.xml**

```
<resource-ref id="FrontEnd_DataSource">
        <description>DB2 database</description>
        <res-ref-name>db2_DB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Anyone have idea about this?

**[Root exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype]**

Answer (score 0):

You might need to upgrade the Websphere to 8.5.5.12 or higher. See [PI79731](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI79731)